# C# exception thrown when parsing JSON String

Tags: c#, json

I'm studying C# and trying to get the code below to parse an incoming JSON recipe string that I convert to an XML document and I'm getting the following error

```
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonReaderException(Utf8JsonReader& json, ExceptionResource resource, Byte nextByte, ReadOnlySpan`1 bytes)
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ConsumeStringAndValidate(ReadOnlySpan`1 data, Int32 idx)
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ConsumeString()
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ConsumeValue(Byte marker)
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadSingleSegment()
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.Read()
   at System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(ReadOnlySpan`1 utf8JsonSpan, Utf8JsonReader reader, MetadataDb& database, StackRowStack& stack)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(ReadOnlyMemory`1 utf8Json, JsonReaderOptions readerOptions, Byte[] extraRentedBytes)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(ReadOnlyMemory`1 json, JsonDocumentOptions options)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(String json, JsonDocumentOptions options)
```

I'm unsure as to why it's not working as the data I send to parse is a string. It works for simple strings however when sending a 'recipe' it throws the exception. The recipe is just a string that I create an XML document from (learning exercise). The recipe code is valid but it seems the JSON reader has issues parsing this string, I could be wrong in this. Here's the code:

TCP receive data method

```
 private async Task Listen()
        {
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    TcpClient client = await server.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine("Connected!");
                    await Task.Run(async () => await HandleDevice(client), Token);
                }
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", e);
            }
        }


private async Task HandleDevice(TcpClient client)
        {
            string imei = String.Empty;

            string data = null;
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[80196];
            int i;


            try
            {
                using (stream = client.GetStream())
                {
                    while ((i = await stream.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length, Token)) != 0)
                    {
                        Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                        string hex = BitConverter.ToString(bytes);
                        data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                        Console.WriteLine(data);
                        processData(data);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", e.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                client.Close();
            }
        }
```

Process data method

```
public static void processData(string data)
{
    var jsonOptions = new JsonDocumentOptions
    {
        AllowTrailingCommas = true,
    };

    using (JsonDocument document = JsonDocument.Parse(data, jsonOptions))
    {

        JsonElement root = document.RootElement;

        // FOR DEBUGGING
        // foreach (JsonProperty element in root.EnumerateObject())
        //{
        //  Console.WriteLine($"{element.Name} ValueKind={element.Value.ValueKind} Value={element.Value}");
        //}

        // Parse the data response
        if (root.TryGetProperty("data", out JsonElement contentToParse))
        {

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentToParse.GetString()) == false)
            {

                // Data to parse
                if (contentToParse.GetString().Contains("RECIPE:"))
                {
                    string[] recipe = contentToParse.GetString().Split(':');
                    sendToFront(recipe[1]);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Something else to parse {0}", contentToParse.GetString());
                }

            }

        }

    }
}
```

My incoming JSON String looks like this: `{"user": "me", "data": "RECIPE:<?xml version='1.0'..."}` - The response is valid JSON and tested by online validators.

**UPDATE:** I've inspected the issue via console and it appears that only part of the recipe is received which could be causing the issue. How can I get the full JSON string before sending it to the `processData` method?

Comment: You haven't shown us the receive code. I'm a bit rusty with sockets but I'd guess you can keep testing whether there's more data ready and receiving until there isn't, perhaps allowing a few hundred ms for more data to arrive. Or put end of message marker in your protocol, and wait for that, etc.

Comment: @Rup - Sorry, updated the code above which includes the listen and handle methods

Comment: `ReadAsync` doesn't necessarily read a full JSON object, it might be more or less than one whole object. You need some kind of framing so that you know where one ends and the next begins. A common solution is to read a 4-byte `size` value from the stream, then read that many bytes. A `StreamReader` can do this quite neatly

Comment: Also yeah: XML inside JSON, really?

Comment: @Charlieface - Yeah, I realise I could JSON decode an incoming object and then send it to XmlDocument but for this learning it is more about handling varying data types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @StephenCleary, you need some kind of framing mechanism.

A simple one is to just prefix each string with its length when sending it. Then you read the length, and use `StreamReader` to read that many bytes.

```cs
private async Task HandleDevice(TcpClient client)
{
    Char[] length = new Char[2];
    Char[] data = new Char[80196];

    try
    {
        using (var stream = client.GetStream())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            while ((i = await reader.ReadBlockAsync(bytes.AsMemory(), Token)) != 0)
            {
                var toRead = ((int)length[0]) | (((int)length[1]) << 16);
                var charsRead = await reader.ReadBlockAsync(data.AsMemory(0, toRead), Token);
                var str = new string(data, 0, charsRead);
                Console.WriteLine(str);
                if (charsRead != toRead)
                    throw new EndOfStreamException("Unexpected end of stream");

                processData(str);
                Array.Clear(data);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", e.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        client.Close();
    }
}
```

There are more efficient implementations, but this should suffice for most purposes.

Comment: How would this prefix work as the order of receiving isn't guaranteed. I could receive "user" part first or the "data" - unless I have that wrong?

Comment: The whole JSON string would be prefixed. Eg the string `{"user": "me", "data": "RECIPE:<?xml version='1.0'..."}` would be prefixed with 56

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with the JSON parser. It's getting an incomplete string from your socket code.

The best and easiest solution (by far) is to communicate at a higher abstraction; i.e., self-host ASP.NET Core instead of reinventing it using a custom TCP/IP protocol.

But if you *must* use a custom protocol, you'll need to design it correctly. I have a [blog series](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/tcpip-net-sockets-faq.html) that may help; in particular note the article on [message framing](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html), which is what is causing this particular problem. For a more complete guide, I have a [video series on properly implementing a custom protocol using .NET](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLIebvSMVr_dehKSoq6vuAW0BGEM6QnDlS) - it is not for the faint of heart.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to your blog.