# C# TCP server receive multiple JSON responses issue

Tags: c#, tcpclient

I'm learning C# and I've got a TCP server that works asynchronously and supports multiple connected clients that I'm having trouble keeping a consistent flow to a method `processData(String)` . I think I've managed to trace the issue down to the byte buffer where if I receive data from multiple clients (also if a single client sends the same data multiple times in quick succession).

I've tried using an isWorking bool to prevent `processData()` from being accessed and that threw a `JSONReader Exception` because I think the buffer was sending the incomplete string from processing. At this point I tried sending a `EOF` at the end of a string and having the `processData()` accessed when the check was true. However, this presented another problem where the buffer would contain half of one string and the beginning of another - at this point I posted on here thinking there may be a better approach to ensure properly formatted Strings were sent to the `processData()` method.

I also tried splitting the response into an array using the `}` as a pointer but this didn't work resulting in the same half of one string and the beginning of another issue.

```
  string data = content.Replace("[EOF]", "");
  string[] TooManyDataObjects = data.Split('}');
  string firstObject = TooManyDataObjects[0] += "}";
```

Here's the code I use to create a listen task and the `handleDevice()` method when a device connects.

```
 private async Task Listen()
        {
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    TcpClient client = await server.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
                    client.NoDelay = true;
                    Console.WriteLine("Connected!");
                    await Task.Run(async () => await HandleDevice(client), Token);
                }
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", e);
            }
        }

        private async Task HandleDevice(TcpClient client)
        {
            string data = null;
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[8196];
            int i;

            try
            {
                using (stream = client.GetStream())
                {
                    while ((i = await stream.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length, Token)) != 0)
                    {
                        Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                        string hex = BitConverter.ToString(bytes);
                        data += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, i);

                        //Console.WriteLine(data);
                        if (data.IndexOf("[EOF]") >= 0)
                        {
                            processData(data);
                            data = "";
                            Array.Clear(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                        }
                  
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", e.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                client.Close();
            }
        }
```

**Question:** How can I get properly formatted string JSON responses received from clients to `processData()` in a queued or the received processing order?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# exception thrown when parsing JSON String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73164383/c-sharp-exception-thrown-when-parsing-json-string)

Comment: This was asked and answered yesterday: You need to be aware of how your framing works: your framing is currently dumping the entire rest of the array, because `stream.ReadAsync` returns any amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm learning C# and I've got a TCP server that works asynchronously

Sorry, but you're trying to learn three fairly complex topics *simultaneously*? I *strongly* recommend you learn C#, sockets, and asynchrony one at a time. C# and asynchrony are fairly common, so I'd recommend learning those first; socket development is much more rare, so I'd learn that only if necessary.

> the buffer would contain half of one string and the beginning of another

This is a common problem when starting out with socket programming. My first response to everyone running into this is to drop the sockets completely and use something much higher-level like ASP.NET Core (self-hosted if necessary).

But if you need sockets for some reason, then the proper solution for *this* socket problem (the first of several usually encountered) is message framing. I discuss [message framing](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html) on my blog, as part of a series on [socket programming in .NET](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/tcpip-net-sockets-faq.html). I also have a video series I did earlier this year on [asynchronous socket programming](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLIebvSMVr_dehKSoq6vuAW0BGEM6QnDlS) that would be well worth watching if you really need to learn socket programming (again, the vast majority of developers never need to learn that).